# How Can Asynchronous Function Result Be returned in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, firebase, angularfire

I have created the service below.

```
    app.factory('userProfileFactory', ['FBDB', 'searchParam', function(FBDB, searchParam) {
            var personalKey;
        return {

            userProfile: function() {
                var FBref = new Firebase(FBDB).child('items');
                FBref.orderByChild('first')
                    .startAt(searchParam)
                    .endAt(searchParam)
                    .once('value', function (snapshot) {
                    var data = snapshot.val();

                        personalKey = Object.keys(data)[0];

                        return(personalKey);     
                });

                return(personalKey);

            }
        };
    }]);
```

However, when I try to get the results of the value of personalKey in the controller below, I get "undefined":

```
app.controller('profileCtrl', ['userProfileFactory', function(userProfileFactory) {

console.log(userProfileFactory.userProfile())

}]);
```

Please advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could Create a custom promise at that place where you are trying to expecting to get data in asynchrous manner by taking help from `$q`

```
userProfile: function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var FBref = new Firebase(FBDB).child('items');
  var promise = FBref.orderByChild('first')
  .startAt(searchParam)
  .endAt(searchParam)
  .on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    personalKey = Object.keys(data)[0];
    deferred.resolve(personalKey);
  });
  return deferred.promise
}
```

And then controller will call the factory function with `.then` function to chain promise.

```
app.controller('profileCtrl', ['userProfileFactory', function(userProfileFactory) {
    userProfileFactory.userProfile().then(function(res){
      console.log(res);
    })
}]);
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Very grateful :)

Comment: @JohnCarson Glad to help you. Thanks :-)

Comment: @PankajParkar Thank you. I was looking for the same.

Comment: @MunamYousuf Glad to know that I helped you as well, Cheers :)